# How to resolve Skill Checks that can be repeated with no consequence?

Tags: dnd-5e, skills

As a newbie GM, I wonder what happens when a PC fails on a Skill Check, but nothing stops them from rerolling it.

E.g. In the starter set, after defeating a goblin ambush, the players can spot a trail by succeeding on a DC 10 Wisdom(Survival) check.

If a player fails to notice it, couldn't they reroll the check or let another player try with the excuse that they're keep looking for clues?

Comment: One point that's in your question but not in the linked answers: always remember that GMs, not players, call for checks. Ch 7 of the PHB is all cast in terms of "you (player) have these abilities and skills; the GM may call for a check...." What's stopping them from rerolling it is *you*. (Or, as one DM put it, after the second roll comes "the guard is very impressed by your nice dice set. But he's no more intimidated than when you tried to intimidate him.")