# Re-Rolling Skills for Perception/Insight/Sneak

Tags: dnd-5e, skills

When is it appropriate to allow/disallow players to re-roll skill checks?

For instance, a player walks into a room in a dungeon and rolls a 2 on perception.  Do I allow them to re-roll?  If so what's the point in rolling and not just telling them everything the moment they walk into the room.

The players I have always try to roll again and again, I have no problem with them checking around again, but at what point do I have them take a 10 or a 20, and how do I do that organically?

My question isn't about things that are actively in action, but more about those rolls when nothing is happening.  Like if the group is wandering around a dungeon, and stumbles into a room.  How do I handle the perception check for a secret door?  Or a rogue hiding?  Things that don't have an obvious repercussion, unlike failing to pick a lock.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [I failed to open a lock. Now what?](http://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/49239/i-failed-to-open-a-lock-now-what) or maybe more accurately [How to resolve Skill Checks that can be repeated with no consequence?](http://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/73269/how-to-resolve-skill-checks-that-can-be-repeated-with-no-consequence?lq=1) which is closed as a dupe of the previous link anyway.